# Adding literal control inside SSRS custom code

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I would like to have custom code in SSRS create a literal control and display it on the current page. To do this, I need to find an element on the page dynamically, and add the new literal control to that element's controls object.

How can I find an element on the page dynamically, so that I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET code (using VB.Net as that's what I know):

If memory serves, if it's directly on the page, you can use

```
Dim ctl = Page.FindControl("ControlName")
```

Or else if it's in a container, you'd need to get the name of the containing element, say "MainBox1," make sure that it's an item running at the server (i.e., tag contains `runat="server"`), and use something like

```
Dim ctl = MainBox1.FindControl("ControlName")
```

And then

```
Dim ctl2 As New LiteralControl("Text of Literal Control")
ctl.Controls.Add(ctl2)
```

Comment: SSRS doesn't have access to the Page object, as far as I know.

Comment: So sorry, I'm afraid I'm not really familiar with SSRS... I assumed from the ASP.NET tag that you'd have access to the same objects.  Do you have access to `FindControl` at all?

Comment: I can import assembies; so far the only thing related to the page currently being displayed that I have found is "HttpContext.Current". I'm unsure what other globals I could conceivably import from assemblies.

I can import FindControl by importing Web.UI.Control, but I can't actually find a control object.